# C# How to disable the "tour" of Down keys, Up, by the items?

Tags: c#

Well, I created an editor program (football) where the main focus is a combobox.
Which constantly has to be triggered to select the desired team and make changes and etc.
Only it gets very boring and impractical always having to click with the mouse on it to focus it and select the team with the Down and Up keys,
So what I wanted was to disable the "walk" of the Down and Up keys by the other items,
For example: there are 6 radioButtons and when I select the team in the combobox and then I click on a radioButton to mark the modification and save, I would click on Down or Up and the focus will automatically return to the combobox,
And not go down or up to another radioButton or button understood?
Or if the combobox did not lose its focus ever, no matter how much it clicked on another item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     MyCombo.Select();
}
```

Comment: It works with all keys, except the Down and Up keys, When you press Down and Up goes the radiobutton to another. :(

Comment: Then capture `PreviewKeyDown` event.

Comment: Ensure that your form has its KeyPreview set to true. The radio button container is responding to the arrow keys, not the form.